# UploadiFive Как определить id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Работаю с плагином `UploadiFive`
Кто нить знает как получить `id` загружаемого файла в функциях -
`'onAddQueueItem' : function() {тут!}`
и соответственно
`'onUploadComplete'  : function() {тут!}`
Нигде об этом ни слова не сказано.

Comment: `'onUploadComplete'  : function(file) { console.log(file); }` тут ищите

Comment: Если бы все было так просто.)) в этом массиве   - размер, название закаченного файла, имя закаченного файла ) усе)

Comment: А что за id у него дожен быть?

Comment: Он забирает массив файлов и поочередно, после закачки, выкидывает на страницу. Файл с таким то именем - закачен. Там есть внутренний  id для queue(uploadifive-upload-file-1++),но как получить его в функции незнаю???